# tcl : exit or error without displaying code?

Tags: tcl, exit

We have an 'exit -1' command inside a conditional which is nested down inside a few more levels of conditionals.

On redhat linux 5.8, after exiting at the 'exit -1', all of the surrounding / enclosing lines of code are displayed, all the way up to the top level enclosing conditional / enclosing set of braces.

We see the same behavior when using 'error' in place of 'exit'.

Is there a way to suppress this display?

Comment: Surely you have attempted to use the various exception-handling methods before asking?

Answer (score 1):

The manual says "exit terminates the running process", so if this causes code to be displayed your setup must be more complex than you said.

Guessing: your script is `exec`uted by another script, the first one blows up at receiving returncode 255 (result of `exit -1`).

Using `error` would cause a stack trace to be shown - expected behavior.